# How do I find and delete a string at end of a line?

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have lines with this kind of data:

```
SEQ 338 13 OPS POSN 1 THRU 10 LANG KO 3 MO TU WE TH FR SA SU 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SEQ 339 6 OPS POSN 1 THRU 10 LANG CM 3 MO TU WE TH FR SA SU 
-------------------------------- 
SEQ 17011 1 OPS POSN 1 THRU 4 MO TU WE TH FR SA SU 

etc
```

...and wish to detect and delete any digits after the pattern 'SEQ 123456' out of each line. I don't need to delete any other characters after those other digits following the white space of SEQ 1-6 digits

I have tried this RegEX but this fails"

```
[RegEx toggled ON]
FIND: SEQ \d\d\d 13
REPLACE: SEQ \d\d\d
```

...but it replaces everything with 'SEQ ddd '

I would like it to read instead:

```
SEQ 338  OPS POSN 1 THRU 10 LANG KO 3 MO TU WE TH FR SA SU 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SEQ 339  OPS POSN 1 THRU 10 LANG CM 3 MO TU WE TH FR SA SU 
-------------------------------- 
SEQ 17011  OPS POSN 1 THRU 4 MO TU WE TH FR SA SU
```

Appreciate the clarifying help

Comment: Which tool are you using? You might need to replace `(SEQ \d\d\d) 13` by `\1` or `$1` (depending on the tool).

Comment: @harrymc I am using Notepad ++
I tried every combination of using either \1 $1 but that completely errors in Notepad ++

Comment: Notepad++, find `(SEQ \d\d\d) 13`, replace by `\1`, works fine for me. Perhaps your data is different than what is posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^SEQ \d+\K \d+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
SEQ             # SEQ followed by a space
\d+             # 1 or more digits
\K              # match reset operator, forget all we have seen until this position
 \d+            # a space followed by 1 or more digit
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

[match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)

Comment: My apologies. I thought it didn't matter that there was other text in the file so that solution finds the last two characters on every line in the file. I want to search out only the text in the original question.

Sorry that wasn't clear

Comment: @JeffTaylor: See my edit.

Comment: (fyi using Notepad ++)

using \h without the $ does select, for example this:

"SEQ 451 1 "

...but cannot use the REPLACE regex to clear the "1 ", I guess because it's related to the missing $

Reading the Tutorial you sent, seems $ is intended for the last position at end of line ("asserts position at the end of a line"). It's not the last character however. There is more text I don't care about after this number "13"

Comment: @JeffTaylor: Sorry, I don't understand. My regex works with your example as you can see in regex101.com. Please, edit your question add show real test cases and expected result.

Comment: Np, Toto...I have added additional clarity to the original question. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Toto, appreciate the solution and lesson.